# Pandas column of lists into index list accounting for zeros and duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have a dataframe with a column of lists with zeros and duplicate values and am attempting to create another column with their corresponding order values in ascending order but accounting for zeros by:

- Having any zero in the original list as a zero in the order list
- Values in the order list start at 1 for the first number above zero
- Any duplicate values are assigned an equal order value but the next value or values are skipped. Eg. if 2 duplicates, next value is +2, if 3 duplicates, next value is +3, etc.

Code so far:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'original_list': [[1.8, 8.3, 8.6, 20.8, 34.7, 8.6, 5.7, 29.7], [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 6, 7, 0, 3, 3]]})

df['order_list'] = df['original_list'].apply(lambda x: [0 if elem == 0 else sorted(range(len(x)), key=lambda i: (x[i], i))[:x.count(elem)].index(x.index(elem)) + 1 for elem in x])
```

Output:

```
0              [0, 2, 3, 5, 7, 3, 1, 6]
1    [0, 2, 3, 3, 3, 8, 9, 10, 0, 6, 6]
```

Desired output:

```
0              [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 4, 2, 7]
1     [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 7, 8, 9, 0, 5, 5]
```

The problem is ensuring the order values start at one and accounting for lists where there are zeros as the order starts at 0 + (number of zeros).

Comment: difficult to understand the logic. Please show how the logic is applied to each example so that we can understand why your input t is desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just modify the lambda function to get the desired output.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'original_list': [[1.8, 8.3, 8.6, 20.8, 34.7, 8.6, 5.7, 29.7], [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 6, 7, 0, 3, 3]]})

df['order_list'] = df['original_list'].apply(lambda x: [0 if elem == 0 else sorted(range(len(x)), key=lambda i: (x[i], i)).index(x.index(elem)) + 1 for elem in x])

def adjust_order(order_list):
    order_adjusted = []
    zero_count = order_list.count(0)
    for order in order_list:
        if order == 0:
            order_adjusted.append(0)
        else:
            order_adjusted.append(order + zero_count)
            zero_count = 0
    return order_adjusted

df['order_list'] = df['order_list'].apply(adjust_order)
print(df['order_list'])
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
0              [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 4, 2, 7]
1     [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 7, 8, 9, 0, 5, 5]
```

After creating the original order list, I define the function adjust_order, which modifies the order values to start at 1 for the first number above zero and takes into account the amount of zeros in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get this to work by summing elements in the list that are not zero, and handle the case where there are duplicates of an element and only count duplicates that appear before the current element.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'original_list': [[1.8, 8.3, 8.6, 20.8, 34.7, 8.6, 5.7, 29.7], [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 6, 7, 0, 3, 3]]})
df['order_list'] = df['original_list'].apply(lambda x: [0 if elem == 0 else sum(1 for i in x if i < elem and i != 0 or (i == elem and x.index(i) < x.index(elem))) + 1 for elem in x])
```

Output:

```
0              [1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 4, 2, 7]
1     [0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 7, 8, 9, 0, 5, 5]
```